# How to develop a script that can be impletement some du function in UNIX shell script

Tags: shell, unix, getopt, du

I have some questions about how to implement some du function in UNIX shell (/bin/sh)
 when I want to write a script to exec some commands.

1)To avoid confusion with the real du command, how can I name that du to a new name like e.g."disku"?

2)I want to use "getopt" to accept a command line argument that specifies the name of a
starting directory in either absolute or relative notation. (e.g. If the present working
directory is /home and we wanted to process directory /home/foo and all of its subdirectories,
the command line could be:

```
disku -d /home/foo or
disku -d foo or
disku -d ./foo
All three forms must work.)
```

so how can write in a script that list each file in the directory and report its size as the
number of 512 byte units rounded up to the next 512 byte unit.

SO How can I use the built-in getopt function to parse command line argument.?

then how can I implementation of the h and -s options?

cheers

Comment: This is a little broad . . . firstly it seems that you have two unrelated questions, and then the second question doesn't really show what you've tried so far.  I'd break this question down into more bite-sized chunks of work.

Answer (score 0):

1) To set du to new name like disku use `alias`

```
alias disku=du
```

Put it in some startup scripts to make it consistent across sessions

Comment: That's the other way round.  PO wants to name their own program `disku`, not "rename" the existing `du`.